# Packets dropped connecting to Azure VM through Point-to-Site RM Gateway

Tags: vpn, routing, azure, rm

I've setup a point-to-site Virtual Network Gateway using the Resource Manager model. I followed both of these instructions:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/

http://www.techdiction.com/2016/01/12/creating-a-point-to-site-vpn-connection-on-an-azure-resource-manager-virtual-network/

Here is my Azure Virtual Network setup:

```
Address Space: 192.168.0.0/16
Frontend Subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
Backend Subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
GatewaySubnet: 192.168.200.0/24

Vpn Client pool as 192.168.201.0/24
```

I can successfully connect to the VPN, and I'm assigned an address in the client pool. I can successfully ping 192.168.201.1, but when I try and ping anything in the other Azure subnets I don't get a response.

I have a VM with an IP of 192.168.1.4 in the Frontend subnet. When I try tracert to this VM, the first hop is 192.168.201.1 then every subsequent hop times out.

What am I missing??

I've tried adding Azure Route Tables, static routes on my router and routes to my local Windows route table.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ping is disabled on Azure. you will need to use tcping (download off of microsoft)

hope this helps,
Lee